# variable ‘count’ set but not used in c

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, palindrome, unused-variables

This is my palindrome code in c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char toUpperCase(char c) {
    if (c > 'Z') {
        c -= 32;
    }
    return c;
}

int isPalindrom(char word[40]) {
    int count = 0;
    int letterCount = 0;
    char lettersOnly[40];
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        char current = word[i];
        if (current == '\n' || current == '\0') {
            count = i;
            break;
        }
        
        if ((current >= 'A' && current <= 'Z') || (current >= 'a' && current <= 'z')) {
            lettersOnly[letterCount] = current;
            letterCount++;
        }
    }
   
    
   return 1;
}
```

It gives me an error that I set the variable "count" but didn't use it. I clearly used it tho.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You claim: *I clearly used it tho.*  Where would that be in that code? What is the purpose of `count = i;`? You never read the value of `count`.

Comment: `count = i;` assigns a value to it, but that variable isn't used anywhere else in the code. If you deleted that line it would not affect your program in any way.

Comment: It's not an error, just a warning about a useless statement. It also could be an indication of an error somewhere else (maybe you meant to use `count` but mistakenly used a different variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code only sets the value of `count` (`count = i` in the loop). It never reads this value, and thus it's safe to say that the program would have worked the same way had it been removed altogether.